# Facebook Login with easysocial: URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings

Tags: joomla3.5

I am working on joomla 3.5 to integrate facebook login using a package named EasySocial.

All of my credentials like appId and Secrete are correct but I cant get rid of the above error message.

I am trying to test the functionality on subdomain v2.temarinet.com

What would be the solution for this. What could be the valid url for this.

I have tried

1. https://v2.temarinet.com/index.php/temarinet-social/
2. https://v2.temarinet.com/index.php/temarinet-social/
3. https://v2.temarinet.com/_oauth/facebook?close

Help please. I also attached the screenshot of my facebook app.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution after hours of trying. The valid oauth route for Facebook Login on Joomla using easysocial is

https://example.com/index.php/register/oauthDialog/facebook